# Visual Studio 2010 not working with NUnit

Tags: nunit

NUnit version 2.5.10.11092

File, New Class library project.

Used Nuget to install NUnit. Although I have a previous version of NUnit that goes back to 2.5.9.10348 installed on my laptop (64bit win7) when I was using VS08.

I have since upgraded to VS2010 and am experiencing I suppose a versioning problem with NUnit.

After creating the class library project and using Nuget to install the latest and greatest NUnit, I add my using statements `using NUnit.Framework;` , add my attributes, `[TestFixture]` for the class and `[Test]` for the method under test and there are NO NUnit icons on the left bar, that allow you to run the test.

What can I do to fix this versioning problem so that I can run NUnit projects in VS2010???

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio never had built in support for nUnit as you describe this has always been done with add-ons like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) - you probably need to install the add-on you have used with VS 2008 for VS 2010.

You can try [TestDriven.NET](http://testdriven.net/) (also available through NuGet) and of course, you can always run the nUnit GUI directly and selecting your test assemblies.